# How can I get a firebase query to work with esbuild?

Tags: javascript, firebase, esbuild

I followed the tutorial on the firebase docs for ['Using Firebase with esbuild'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling#using_firebase_with_esbuild).

My project consists of one `.html` file and one `.mjs` file.

The `.html` file contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="dist/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `.mjs` file is largely copied from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en&authuser=0#simple_queries) and contains:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, getDocs, count } from "firebase/firestore/lite";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "0000000000000",
    appId: "1:0000000000000:web:0000000000000",
    measurementId: "X-XXXXXXXXX"
  };

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

const q = query(collection(db, "db_name"), where("created_on", ">=", 1699333200000), where("created_on", "<=", 1699376399999), count());

getDocs(q)
    .then(querySnapshot =>
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        })
    );
```

When I run my build task `esbuild src/index.mjs --bundle --sourcemap=inline --outdir=dist --allow-overwrite`, it creates the `dist/index.js` file and when I serve the application with a very simple http server, the html file is retrieved and the dist/index.js file is retrieved as well. But then I receive the following error message:

> e2._apply is not a function
> at query (query.ts:175:24)

This error is being thrown from the `node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/lite-api/query.ts`.

How can I perform a query with firebase using an esbuild build?